# How to get the first value of span within a dynamic li which inside another dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the HTML structure

```
<div class="a">
   <ul class="b">
       <li class="c">
           <span>123</span>
       </li>

       <li class="c">
           <span>345</span>
       </li>

       <li class="c">
          <span>678</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
        <li class="c">
            <span>976</span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
        <li class="c">
            <span>234</span>
        </li>   
        <li class="c">
            <span>789</span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of first span of each dynamic div in a for loop.Here the challenge is the li is also dynamic.There can be 1 to 4 li within a div.

When I try to loop,I am getting all the span values.Please suggest a solution
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: please share the code you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` and use `nth-child(1)` in selector for first child.

```
div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)
```

Here the working snippet

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll('div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)');
x.forEach(x => console.log(x.innerHTML))
```

```html
<div class="a">
   <ul class="b">
       <li class="c">
           <span>123</span>
       </li>

       <li class="c">
           <span>345</span>
       </li>

       <li class="c">
          <span>678</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
        <li class="c">
            <span>976</span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
        <li class="c">
            <span>234</span>
        </li>   
        <li class="c">
            <span>789</span>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the jQuery tag so I figured I would drop in an alternate solution if you're using jQuery in your project anyway

```
$('.a ul').each(function(i, v) {
    console.log($(v).find('span').first());
})
```

if you want to make sure that the span is inside of an li then you can be more specific but there shouldnt really be a need outside of an odd case

```
$('.a ul').each(function(i, v) {
 console.log($(v).find('li span').first());
})
```